# How to make automatically break a long compound word with hyphenation

Tags: hyphenation, indic

I am using polyglossia and the text is in Sanskrit Language. I am expecting the break with hyphenation, but the the line crosses the margin. I even tried with \enablehyphenation and did not work.

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage,openany]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{sanskrit}
\setmainfont{Sanskrit2003}

\begin{document} 

पुरन्दरत्रिपुरहरवसुविरिञ्चिपावकपवमानहिमभानुचित्रभानुकृशानुनिखिलनक्षत्रगणसकलसुरासुरयक्षगन्धर्वकिन्नरचारणसिद्धसाध्यनरनागलोकपालनाकपालकालकरालव्यालमालमौलिसम्पूजितपादारविन्दलेखाधीशमुकुटमणिसंलालितचरणसरोजरजोमकरन्दत्रैलोक्यलक्ष्मीनवनलिनललितलोचनलसितकमनकटाक्षसंवीक्षितशुभेक्षितभव्यसौन्दर्यसारसर्वस्वसकलसुषमासारभूतमनोरमसार्वभौमशर्वरीप्राणवल्लभसंव्रीडकमदनमानपीडकवदनसरसीरुहनिसर्गनिहितसुधितसुधामाधुरीकश्रीवत्सलाञ्छनशरच्छशाङ्काननमधुरमन्दस्मिततुहिनांशुदीधितिविहितप्रपन्नहृदयसरसीकैरवविकासललितलीलाविलासमहालक्ष्मीनिवासक्षीरसागरसम्मन्थनसञ्जातकणसंस्पर्शभग्नभक्तभूरिभवभयव्रणपाणिपल्लवजगतीतलपाथोधिप्लवनाशितप्रणिपातक्लवविरचितगणिकागजाजामिलपङ्किलपङ्ककलङ्कभवविहितभवसंस्तवकरुणार्णवसकलशरण्यवरेण्यतरुणारुणसरसिजचरणतरुणतमालनीलसरसीरुहमरकतमणिकालिन्दीकीलालविनिन्दकभुवनाभिरामश्यामशरीरदामिनीद्युतिविनिन्दकसंवीतपीतपरिधानम्लानमदमत्तमनोभवधीरमधुकैटभनरकमुरप्रचुरमहासुरभूरिमदगर्वितगजेन्द्रगण्डस्थलविनिर्गतशोणितकरकमलकलितकौमोदकीधरशङ्खचक्रधरकमलकलितकमलकरकेयूरकुण्डलकटकवनमालानूपुरादिभूषणमण्डितसकलकलाकलापपण्डितकमलामलमुखचन्द्रचकोरवैकुण्ठविहरणपरायणनारायणप्रभविष्णुविष्णुर्हृदयमन्दिरे महीयते। अस्य प्रायशो विश्वस्मिन् विश्वे प्रचारः प्रसारश्च।

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Is there really a 797 character long word in Sanskrit?

Comment: Yes its ! Some times even the book completely will be like this. What is the solution?

Comment: You need to load the correct hyphenation patterns (enable hyphenation between any vowel and following consonant); they are included with TeX somewhere. Trying to find it…

Comment: Oh now I remember: IIRC it's a bug (accepted as feature) in TeX that it does not hyphenate the first word of a paragraph (that you can work around) and that it does not hyphenate words more than 63 characters long. (Some of these are fixed with LuaTeX, but LuaTeX has its own issues dealing with complex scripts…) Your best bet is to insert discretionary hyphens explicitly. (Or even non-discretionary: they will help the reader.)

Answer (score 5):

The problem you're running into is that (Xe)TeX cannot hyphenate words that are more than 63 characters long. However, as you're using XeTeX, you can work around this using its `\XeTeXinterchartoks` feature.

The idea is to recognize Devanagari vowels and consonants, and insert discretionary hyphens between them (this is what the hyphenation pattern loaded by polyglossia tries to do anyway).

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage,openany]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{sanskrit}
\setmainfont{Sanskrit 2003}

% Enable the character classes functionality
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate = 1
% Define new character classes for Devanagari-script consonants (with implicit 'a') and for vowel signs
\newXeTeXintercharclass \DevanagariConsonant
\newXeTeXintercharclass \DevanagariVowelSign
\newcount\tmpchar
% Assign characters (code points) क to ह (in the Unicode block for Devanagari) to "consonant" class
\tmpchar = `क
\loop
  \XeTeXcharclass \tmpchar = \DevanagariConsonant
  \ifnum \tmpchar < `ह
    \advance \tmpchar by 1
\repeat
% Assign characters (code points) ा to ौ to "vowel sign" class
\tmpchar = `ा
\loop
  \XeTeXcharclass \tmpchar = \DevanagariVowelSign
  \ifnum \tmpchar < `ौ
    \advance \tmpchar by 1
\repeat
% Define what to insert at transition between these character classes (discretionary hyphen)
\XeTeXinterchartoks \DevanagariConsonant \DevanagariConsonant = {\-}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \DevanagariVowelSign \DevanagariConsonant = {\-}

\begin{document}

पुरन्दरत्रिपुरहरवसुविरिञ्चिपावकपवमानहिमभानुचित्रभानुकृशानुनिखिलनक्षत्रगणसकलसुरासुरयक्षगन्धर्वकिन्नरचारणसिद्धसाध्यनरनागलोकपालनाकपालकालकरालव्यालमालमौलिसम्पूजितपादारविन्दलेखाधीशमुकुटमणिसंलालितचरणसरोजरजोमकरन्दत्रैलोक्यलक्ष्मीनवनलिनललितलोचनलसितकमनकटाक्षसंवीक्षितशुभेक्षितभव्यसौन्दर्यसारसर्वस्वसकलसुषमासारभूतमनोरमसार्वभौमशर्वरीप्राणवल्लभसंव्रीडकमदनमानपीडकवदनसरसीरुहनिसर्गनिहितसुधितसुधामाधुरीकश्रीवत्सलाञ्छनशरच्छशाङ्काननमधुरमन्दस्मिततुहिनांशुदीधितिविहितप्रपन्नहृदयसरसीकैरवविकासललितलीलाविलासमहालक्ष्मीनिवासक्षीरसागरसम्मन्थनसञ्जातकणसंस्पर्शभग्नभक्तभूरिभवभयव्रणपाणिपल्लवजगतीतलपाथोधिप्लवनाशितप्रणिपातक्लवविरचितगणिकागजाजामिलपङ्किलपङ्ककलङ्कभवविहितभवसंस्तवकरुणार्णवसकलशरण्यवरेण्यतरुणारुणसरसिजचरणतरुणतमालनीलसरसीरुहमरकतमणिकालिन्दीकीलालविनिन्दकभुवनाभिरामश्यामशरीरदामिनीद्युतिविनिन्दकसंवीतपीतपरिधानम्लानमदमत्तमनोभवधीरमधुकैटभनरकमुरप्रचुरमहासुरभूरिमदगर्वितगजेन्द्रगण्डस्थलविनिर्गतशोणितकरकमलकलितकौमोदकीधरशङ्खचक्रधरकमलकलितकमलकरकेयूरकुण्डलकटकवनमालानूपुरादिभूषणमण्डितसकलकलाकलापपण्डितकमलामलमुखचन्द्रचकोरवैकुण्ठविहरणपरायणनारायणप्रभविष्णुविष्णुर्हृदयमन्दिरे महीयते। अस्य प्रायशो विश्वस्मिन् विश्वे प्रचारः प्रसारश्च।

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note that there are a lot of “Overfull \hbox” warnings and the text is not perfectly justified (XeTeX has not managed to correctly compute the widths of words). I don't know why, but that seems to be a separate problem, worth asking a new question about. You could typeset your entire document ragged-right (i.e., without justification), so that it's less glaring.

In my opinion it would be even better to add explicit (or at least discretionary) hyphens at semantically meaningful places (e.g. “पुरन्दर-त्रिपुरहर-वसु-विरिञ्चि-पावक-पवमान-हिमभानु-चित्रभानु-कृशानु-निखिल-नक्षत्रगण-सकल-सुरासुर-यक्ष-गन्धर्व-किन्नर-चारण-…”); it will surely help the reader.