# Increasing the number of allowed hyphenation exceptions in XeLaTeX?

Tags: xetex, hyphenation

I'm trying to load a huge hyphenation exception dictionary in XeLaTeX, and I'm greeted with the following error message:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [exception dictionary=8191].
```

Is it possible to increase this limit? There's no such limitation in LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In texlive at least (not sure about miktex) you can increase that value in `texmf.cnf` the relevant section is

```
% Hyphenation trie.  The maximum possible is 4194303 (ssup_trie_size in
% the sources), but we don't need that much.  The value here suffices
% for all known free hyphenation patterns to be loaded simultaneously
% (as TeX Live does).
%
trie_size = 1000000

hyph_size = 8191        % prime number of hyphenation exceptions, >610, <32767.
                        % http://primes.utm.edu/curios/page.php/8191.html
```

Alternatively you could keep that as it is, but load fewer languages.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to raise the value to 65535, but it won't increase further. Looks like an `unsigned short` is hiding somewhere...

Comment: The comment says not to go above 32767 so code is probably not tested above that (or more likely known to go wrong) is that not big enough? @michaelmeyer

Comment: Unfortunately, no, because I'm trying to load a full dictionary of about 200,000 entries. I understand that this somewhat stretches the purpose of an "exception" dictionary, but this is the most convenient way in my case, because the language (Sanskrit) is notoriously hard to segment correctly. I will find some workaround.

Comment: @michaelmeyer What are some example entries in your list of hyphenation exceptions? Note that polyglossia for Sanskrit plays some tricks with `\XeTeXinterchartoks` to allow hyphenation after every vowel sign but not inside a consonant cluster; something like that may be worth exploring. Another option of course is to just insert the (discretionary or even explicit) hyphens into your `.tex` source, after having generated the text elsewhere. (See also a related answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/404758/48).)

Comment: can not patgen at least get some set of patterns to reduce the size of the exception list?  You could ask on the xetex list if it is possible to enlarge the sources. Also you may be interested in harftex which would give you the same harfbuzz based font shaping as xetex but with dynamic hyphenation dictionary as in luatex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks a lot, I'm going to explore this.